# How to swap day and month?

Tags: javascript

How to swap day and month?

Now I have an input in which the user enters his birthday in the format **"dd/mm/yyyy"**

Next i do
***new Date (e.target.value)*** and get **mm/dd/yyyy**

But how to get what the user entered? I.e **"dd/mm/yyyy"**

Comment: Where is your code or HTML or JS ? Its hard to understand what you want here are tring to code.

Comment: `new Date(...event.target.value.match(/(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+)/).slice(1).map((x,i)=>i===1?x-1:x).reverse())`

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-visvesvaraya-bxs67?file=/src/App.js
10/09/1997 - mm/dd/yyyy (9 oct 1997)
And how to make dd / mm / yyyy? (10 sep 1997)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If user input is a string, and you know for sure that it's "dd/mm/yyyy" then you need to parse the string and make a date out of that parsed string.

```js
const inputDate = '31/12/2020';
const splited = inputDate.split('/');
const swaped = [splited[1], splited[0], splited[2]];

const swapedDate = new Date(swaped);
```

Comment: The splitting approach might solve the purpose for now. But, the recommended and general approach is to use the methods like getMonth(), getDate(), etc., to get the required output. Consider an example where you are getting the format as 10-23-2002, in that case, the split approach will fail

Comment: Correct approach - is fixing the input so that there's no need to use any workarounds.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly pass your mm/dd/yyyy to new Date() and modify the output accordingly

```
x = new Date('10/23/1996')
=> Wed Oct 23 1996 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

// x is your date object now
```

Then you can do

```
x.getMonth()
=> 9 // You need to add +1 for month

x.getDate()
=> 23

x.getFullYearYear()
=> 1996
```

with these methods you can get your required data and format accordingly

Answer (score 0):

You can try out this as well.,

```js
var today = new Date();
var date = today.getDate()+'/'+(today.getMonth()+1)+'/'+ today.getFullYear();
console.log(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert the date to dd/mm/yyyy you can write:

```
let current_date = new Date (e.target.value);
let formatted_date = current_date.getDate()+"/"+ (current_date.getMonth() + 1 ) + "/" + current_date().getFullYear();
```

Answer (score 0):

Improvement upon @Ivan Satsiuk. Change to slashes instead.

```
const inputDate = '31/12/2023';
const splited = inputDate.split('/');
const swaped = [splited[1]+"/" + splited[0] +"/" + splited[2]];
document.write(inputDate)
// Returns 12/31/2023
```